# How to take inputs from <Input/> in react semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I've been trying to take inputs from an `input` field and i used `refs`(the usual way in `react`), But it doesn't seem to be working. The `input` i'm getting is `undefined`. This is my code:

```
sendMessage = () => {
   console.log(this.inputtext.value);
}

render(){
   return(
      <div>
         <Input ref={input => this.inputtext = input;} placeholder='message'/>
         <Button onClick={this.sendMessage}>Send</Button>
      </div>
   );
}
```

I need to take the inputs from the `click event` of the button. I can't figure out what's wrong. How can i get the `input` value properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have used the `arrow` operator, `this.inputtext.value` won't work,
you need to write:

```
sendMessage(){
  console.log(this.inputtext.value);
}
```

In this case semantic-ui's `Input` Component is a `div` wrapped on top of `input`. So you cannot access input element directly through ref. You should use the react's preferred way to get the value, which is

```
<Input onChange={this.handleMessage.bind(this)} placeholder='message'/>


handleMessage (e) { console.log(e.target.value); }
```

or without using bind, `babel-preset-stage-2` is required for this.

```
<Input onChange={this.handleMessage} placeholder='message'/>


handleMessage = e => { console.log(e.target.value); }
```

Answer (score 9):

In your case, you can also get the input value through this code:

```
this.inputtext.inputRef.value
```

Comment: Yep this is what I do as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a normal class method for this to work. You also shouldn't have a semi-colon in the ref.

```
sendMessage() {
    console.log(this.inputtext.value);
  }

  render(){
     return(
       <div>
        <Input ref={input => this.inputtext = input} placeholder='message'/>
        <Button onClick={this.sendMessage}>Send</Button>
      </div>
   );
  }
```

Comment: im still getting it as undefined

Comment: As @Vikramaditya said it is due to `Input` not passing the ref prop to the `input` tag it generates. Try just using a plain `input` tag.